# Confusion with scala flatMap, Map and Flatten

Tags: scala

Please follow the below code.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

def myFunc(map : HashMap[Char,List[MyObject]], text : List[Char]) : List[MyObject] = {

  text.flatMap(ch => map.get(ch))          //Gives compilation error 
  text.map(ch => map.get(ch)).flatten      //gives compilation error
  text.flatMap(ch => map.get(ch)).flatten  //This works
}
```

I don't understand why the 1st two methods don't work?

**Edit**
I get this error for the first 2 lines

```
Expression List[List[MyObject]] doesn't confirm  to expected type list List[MyObject]
```

Comment: What are the errors? Is it "pure expression used in an unpure context" or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion here is with the `HashMap.get()` function. The get function returns you an `Option[List[MyObject]]`. That is why when you flatten it (like in the 3rd example), it removes the Option.

[Read more on Scala Options here.](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html)

Comment: Thanks, this really answered my question!